# pl sql function select into variable in loop on a returning table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I have a type object as below
Emptable type is empname,empid,rank

Then I have a Plsql function as below and this errors out. I need to run a sql select statement against the returned list of empids and load it the returned list. and below code keeps erroring..

```
create or replace function emp_details return emptable
  is
     l_result_col  emptable := emptable();
     n integer := 0;
     rxvalue number;
  begin
     for r in (select empname,empid from table)
     loop
        l_result_col.extend;
        n := n + 1;
        (select sum(xyz) into rxvalue from A inner join B on A.x=B.x and A.id=r.empid);
       l_result_col(n) := t_col(r.empname, r.empid,rxvalue);
     end loop;
     return l_result_col;
  end;
  /
```

Any Help is appreciated.. 
Thank you!

Comment: Saying what error you get might be helpful, no? And showing your type declarations. Do you get a compilation or runtime error? (It might just not like the brackets around the `select`, and I think your `and` should be a `where`).

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it straightforward without involving PL/SQL code?

```
select t_col(r.empname, r.empid, sum(xyz))
bulk collect into l_result_col
from table r
left join (A join B on A.x = B.x) on A.id = r.empid
group by r.empname, r.empid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your select shouldn't be in parentheses. In this context it is not a subselect but a separate PL/SQL statement.